# What happens when you divide by 0 in a shader?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, glsl, shader

Branching is known to be particularly computationally expensive in a OpenGL ES shader. In such a shader, I check if a value is null before dividing by it, for example:

```
if(value == 0.0)
    other_value = 0.0;
else
    other_value = 1.0 / value;
```

In order to speed things up, I would like to avoid this `if` by doing directly:

```
other_value = 1.0 / value;
```

I wonder what happened if `value` happens to equal 0, which is a bit rare in my treatment, this is why it is not trivial to test it. Does the shader crash? Does the application crash?

Comment: Is it a big overhead for you to increment value by a tiny floating value like 0.000001 ? this way value will be always > 0.

Comment: http://komplexify.com/images/2010/Divide-by-zero-2.jpg

Comment: Not an answer, but according to [this thread](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=288538) it looks like it's undefined behavior but does continue to run your program.

Comment: @Benj: nice idea, I will probably use it @DarkDust: this is it! I found it in the OpenGL ES Spec: `Treatment of conditions such as divide by 0 may lead to an unspecified result, but must not lead to the interruption or termination of processing.`

Comment: @Benj your suggestion makes no sense since this would make the incremented 'other_value' be assigned the huge value 1.0 / 0.000001 in the case where other_value begins as 0.0!

Comment: @Jasarien Actually that is dividing by infinity. Dividing by 0 should [explode](http://www.mcdoa.org.uk/images/My_Explosion.jpg) (to infinity)

Comment: For floating point this question isn't really interesting, but what about for integers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never seen a shader crash from something like this. It will most likely result in a garbage value (like nan) and mess up any other calculations you perform with the result. Beyond that I wouldn't worry about it (and definitely not add branching code to prevent it).

Comment: In the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec, it's said that the shader should *not* crash, but the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: This is a bad answer, should not be marked correct. As shown by @bobobobo's answer, you really must "worry about it": it ]messes up the shader and all execution that follows on from it that uses the values (I came here after seeing a live code problem where different hardware produces wildly different end results).

Answer (score 32):

Undefined indeed.

On the iPad simulator, dividing the red component by 0.0 gives 0 (all red is gone from this picture).

[image]

On the iPad hardware, dividing the r component by 0.0 saturates it to full red (ie +infinity clamped).

[image]

So no, you can't rely on undefined behavior at all to produce a consistent result, but nothing bad happens by dividing by 0 in and of itself.

In my shader, I'm dividing rgb values by alpha.  It just so happens that if the alpha value is 0, the pixel doesn't show up anyway, so I don't have a problem with the division going either way (giving 0 or +inf).

Comment: This answer deserves respect since it gives you an empirical case of how unpredicted behavior can cause undesirable and sometimes game/app-breaking results. Shader programmers considering letting the processor handle division by zero in any ol' way it sees fit should take note of this potential disaster. In other words, it may not crash your app, but worse: it may only creep up later when already in the hands of thousands of people trying to read glitched-out graphics.

Answer (score 7):

Branches like these are typically not expensive. They usually are implemented using predication. That is, the GPU computes both branches but only actually stores the results of the instructions where the predication condition is true. Hence no jump instruction is used. Here's what the assembly code could look like:

```
cmp_eq p0, r0, 0.0   // predicate = (value == 0.0)
(p0) mov r1, 0.0     // other_value = 0.0, if predicate true
(!p0) rcp r1, r0     // other_value = 1.0 / value, if predicate false
```

Note that in this case the second instruction doesn't actually have to be predicated. Anyway, as indicated by others the result of the division (reciprocal) is undefined when the denominator is zero. But as you can see you should be able to get well-defined behavior at the cost of just a couple of cheap instructions (division is typically slow). To my knowledge all GPUs that support real branches (jump instructions) also support predication. The shader compiler will evaluate whether to use predication or a jump, and will usually do the right thing.

Of course if you really don't care about the result of a division by zero then you can save any and all cost of predication.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
float invert_value(in float value)
{
if(value == 0.0)
    return 0.0;
else
    return 1.0 / value;
}
```

you can write

```
float invert_value_ifless(in float value)
{
float sign_value = sign(value);
float sign_value_squared = sign_value*sign_value;
return sign_value_squared / ( value + sign_value_squared - 1.0);
}
```

This returns exactly what you want and has

1. no ifs
2. no divisions by 0

I am not sure if this is actually any faster on recent hardware with predication though.

Comment: Really clever trick! Fast-forward to 2022. Did you ever benchmark your code, comparing it to predication?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to limit yourself to iPhone, why don't you try and see what happens? However, there are no guarantees on what will happen on future hardware that will be running iPhone applications. It could crash. It could do nothing. It could display weird pixels. It could call your mother-in-law. (All since it's undefined behavior.)

Comment: According to the spec, it would do not crash... which I prefer over calling my mother-in-law :-)

Comment: It could launch a nuke or something worse like call your mother-in-law?

Answer (score 1):

on old graphics hardware, a divide-by-zero would result in a value of floating-point infinity, which is actually the right answer. this is unlikely to be what you want, however, because you're probably going to just store the infinity (or something derived from it) in your frame buffer, which is probably a format like RGBA8 that is incapable of distinguishing infinity from 0 or 1.

on newer desktop hardware, it's possible to have a floating-point frame buffer, in which case infinity is a valid thing to store in there - but still unlikely to be what you want, unless your floating-point kung fu is quite advanced.